# Advise on how to implement image slideshow/carousel? ( iOS )

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, slideshow

I've just started out with iOS development and I'm building an app to help myself learn faster.

I've gotten to the stage where I have all the basics of the app nailed down but now I just want to implement a slideshow at the top of my view controller like the one found in the National Parks app and many other apps too - http://wpuploads.appadvice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Nati2.jpg

Any advise or links to tutorials or explanations would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi Dave, Could you eventually create that carousel? what helped you the most? because the raywenderlich guide doesnt really show how to create a carousel, looks more like a kind of gallery.. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Hope this link will help u

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Other simple way to achieve:
Steps to achieve

1. Add all the images in one scroll view.
2. Enable paging for that scroll view.
3. Based on the content offset of the scroll view highlight the appropriate dot(indicator in the bottom).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I should have known old ray wenderlich would have the answer.

Answer (score 9):

you have to download iCarousel code from github https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel.
you can download code from here.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `UICollectionView` with horizontal scrolling.